# Show a video inside an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

We have a small movie of iPhone screen . We would like to show that movie as if its inside an `iPhone` device.

So i would like to take an iPhone image, and play the movie inside its screen.

Using a `mac`, till now i just couldn't find any solution on how to do that .
With `iMovie` it seems bad and very hard for editing .

Are there any other simple solution ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention a simple solution, if you are preparing this for a presentation you could use Powerpoint or Keynote.

Just:

- Add a layer with the photo (cropped in the center if it goes on top)
- Add [a layer with the video](http://www.wikihow.com/Embed-Video-in-PowerPoint) (cropped to the exact screen size if it goes on top)

It's quick and dirty, but works.

Comment: thanks, actually i have already done that using other tool but it seems there is a basic problem here, where all iPhone images on google don't fit with their proportion to the movies i record directly from an iPhone device. So even if i take that video and try to put above an iPhone image, i cant find an image that fit exactly to the movie which is 750-1334 (real iPhone screen size)

Comment: Oh, that's weird. What's your output final size?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a How-to guide that explains how to play a YouTube video inside an iPhone frame, using AppDemoStore platform: [HOW TO: Play a YouTube Video Inside an iPhone Device Image](http://blog.appdemostore.com/2016/02/how-to-play-youtube-video-inside-iphone.html).

The result looks like this: [Starbucks iPhone App Demo Video](https://www.appdemostore.com/embed?id=4883593696378880)

The advantage of this approach is that you can easily embed the video+frame into your website and it will work cross-platform. However, it works only for YouTube videos.

Give it a try and let me know if you need any help - I'm part of the AppDemoStore team.